# Why is the regularized beta function differentiable?

Tags: functions, derivatives, beta-function

We have the definition of Regularized Incomplete Beta Function:
$$I_x (a,b) = \frac{B(x;a,b)}{B(a,b)},$$ where $B(x;a,b)$ is the incomplete Beta function, $B(a,b)$ is the Beta function and $x \in [0,1], a,b > 0$.

> Is the Regularized Incomplete Beta Function differentiable with respect to x ? If yes why ?

I think Regularized Incomplete Beta Function is differentiable since I found differentiation of Regularized Incomplete Beta Function on functions.wolfram.com website but I don't know why.
Thanks in advanced.

---

$$B(x;a,b) := \int_{0}^{x}{t^{a-1} (1-t)^{b-1} dt}$$
$$B(a,b) := \int_{0}^{1}{t^{a-1} (1-t)^{b-1} dt}.$$

Answer (score 2):

By the fundamental theorem of calculus,$$I_x^\prime=\frac{B_x^\prime}{B(a,\,b)}=\frac{x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}}{B(a,\,b)}.$$This at least ensures differentiability on $(0,\,1)$. As $x\to0^+$, $B_x\sim\int_0^xt^{a-1}dt=x^a/a$, so $B_0=0=\lim_{x\to0^+}B_x$. We can treat $x\to1^-$ similarly.

Comment: I've edited my answer to address the comments.

Comment: @GiaLe Thanks; fixed.

Comment: One point more. Requirement of the fundamental theorem of calculas is that f is continuous on closed interval . But here you consider on (0,1).

Comment: @GiaLe Taking a smaller closed interval, it's differentiable on arbitrary closed interval proper subsets of $[0,\,1]$, and is differentiable on $[0,\,1]$ iff differentiable at the endpoints, and my edit addresses them.